# Output panel refresh Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, refresh

I am calling a JS function to call a pagereference method . This Save button is in an Output panel.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!step4}" id="cciPanel">

   <div align="center" draggable="false">
   <!--<apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" action="{!appenEmailIds}" value="Save" status="busy"/>-->
   <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="appendEmailIds(); return false;" value="Save" status="busy"/>
   <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" value="Cancel" action="{!closePageCDFContact}"/>
                        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;


 <apex:dataTable Some Datatable logic
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="appendEmailIds(); return false;" value="Save" status="busy"/>
```

JS function called from commandbutton

```
function appendEmailIds(){

            appenEmailIds();

}
```

Controller :

```
public pageReference appenEmailIds(){

    //Some logic

    step1 = true;
    step2 = false;
    step3 = false;
    step4  = false;
    userMap = new Map<String, User>();
    getUserOptions();
    prepareJSON();
    return null;
}
```

My requirement is to go back to the same VF Page without refresh . Please help.

Comment: go back means? you just want to stay on that page without refresh right?

Comment: As in the outputpanel should go away and the previous form should come back.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an action function between the backend apex and the javascript call
ie.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="appenEmailIds" action="{!appenEmailIds}" rerender"sectiontoDraw"/>
```